Flutter Doctor - Found an existing Pub cache
I was traying to install Flutter on My pc and In final step in run this commend
" flutter doctor --android-licenses "
and after typing the commend it come this
Found an existing Pub cache at C:\Users\Fares\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache.
It can be repaired by running dart pub cache repair.
It can be reset by running dart pub cache clean.

I was traying to install flutter without android studio so I download the flutter folder and java jdk and android sdk

Did you run dart pub cache repair in your terminal?
